# Stop NGINX dev site redirecting to SSL

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have a Ruby on Rails app running on a Linode Server and I am trying to create a staging server to do some testing on. I cloned the Linode and have the server up. I am able to visit the site, however, I get the 'not secure' error in Chrome, so I want to turn ssl off. So in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx.conf I commented out `listen 443 ssl;` and also commented out the lines referencing `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key`. In /etc/nginx/nginx.conf I commented out `ssl_protocols` and `ssl_prefer_server_ciphers`. After doing this I have restarted nginx.

When I visit the IP address, the address part redirects to SSL and I get a message that says `This site can’t be reached`. Why is the site still redirecting to ssl? Am I missing a configuration somewhere?

## EDIT

Here are nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        client_max_body_size 50M;
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        # SSL Settings
        ##

        #ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
    # include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;
        passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
        passenger_ruby /home/deployer/.rbenv/shims/ruby;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

...and sites-enabled/default

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        #listen 443 ssl;

        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env production;
        root /home/deployer/myapp/current/public;
        #index index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name blah.org;

        #ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/blag.combined.crt;
        #ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/blah.key;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root html;
                #client_max_body_size 50M;

        }
}
```

Comment: please share nginx configuration, here ?

Comment: Opps...rookie mistake...just added full config files.